# Load Testing RestFul Api , one time authorization

Tags: jmeter

I need to test wheather API is working or not and also to put load on each of them .

In post man I can do this but how to get it on jmeter.

I have an POST request from where i get access_tokken , then copy this token and put it in other API Header to get response from API .

Here is request json to get access :

```
Response 201 (application/json)Body  {
      "token_type":  "Bearer",
      "expires_in" : 3600,
      "access_token" : "generated_access_token"
  }
```

When run I am getting :

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"access_token":"accesstoken value here"}
```

Need to get this access_token and pass it to other POST body to get reponse .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a Post Processor for the request (child)

```
Variable Names access_token

JSON Path expression `$.access_token`

Match No. 1
```

Then use `${access_token}` for its value ( or `vars.get("access_token")` in JSR223)

For Header of next request add the `HTTP Header Manager` under the second request as below:
[image]

Comment: Where to add ${access_token}.

Comment: when you need it, inside Body Data of next HTTP Request for example

Comment: I need to pass it as header manager , I added ${access_token} , but in request body it showing as it is .Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Authorization: {access_token}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64

Comment: For Header of next request add the `HTTP Header Manager` under the second request . see updated answer

Comment: Done but still the same .

Comment: Name:Authorization Value:${access_token}

Comment: This is what request is going after adding Header manager has you said :      POST http://myurl/api/app/sendotp

POST data:
{
      "mobile_no": 9867908264,
      "is_registered": 1
  }

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Authorization: {accesstoken}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64
Host: losapi.flexiloans.in
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_144)

Comment: do you seen that you have a typo? you use `accesstoken` instead of `access_token`

Comment: Done , Actually I forget to mentioned $ , but do i need to set header manager for each request or is there way to set one header manager for all other request.

Comment: In this specific request you want to take the value **after** first request so header manager must be after first request . so you can put it between the requests also

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you extract access token to variable
[image: JSON Extractor]

Then you use this variable in proper header in other request/requests
[image]