# How to pull the token from Get request's response and input the same to Post request in JMeter for Rest API?

Tags: api, jmeter, rest

I am a beginner in JMeter, trying to perform load test to my Rest API. First, the Get request gets the **access_token** as below:

[image]

Then the following Post request runs with that authorization token to produce the Json, but I am missing something so the Post Request is failing as **Authentication denied** as below,

[image]

Added the **Regular expression extractor** to extract the token from the Get request's response as below:

[image]

Then storing it in the **HTTP Header Manager** in a variable as below

[image]

I am missing to link the value to the Post request, I dont know how to do it, please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load Testing RestFul Api , one time authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671708/load-testing-restful-api-one-time-authorization)

Comment: Tried, but didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In header manager, instead of `access_token`, the header name should be `Authorization`. Please reconfirm this with developer team / retry this same request in postman

The regex expression used should look something like this
`"access_token":"(.*?)"`

Also, another pro tip: because the response to getToken api call is JSON, you can use JSON Post Processor to extract the `access_token` by saying something like `$.access_token`. It is much clean way to process JSON object.

[image]

Comment: Added the JSON post extractor to get the access_token, then add the same into Header Manager as 'Authorization' and value as 'Bearer ${access_token}' but still the second request is failing

Comment: can you give result of the below two  points  #1 Add a Debug Sampler and check if you can see access_token in View Result Tree #2 In View Result Tree check the request object of failing request #3 execute the failing request in Postman

Comment: While testing the two points, it got worked. Thanks Rahul

Comment: Glad it worked. Could you tell the community what was going wrong? It would be an addition to the knowledge base